# How to watch bootstrap accordion with angular in the least expensive manner

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I currently have a bootstrap accordion with an `ng-click` event set on the my panel headings that passes in a string like so:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" ng-click="setActiveAccordion('accordionOne')">
```

In the panel content, on the element with the directive, I have

```
<div my-named-directive active-accordion="activeAccordion">
```

My controller to control the active accordion functionality looks like this:

```
.controller('accordionPanelController', ['$scope', function(scope){
    $scope.activeAccordion = 'null';
    //no accordion open by default

    $scope.setActiveAccordion = function(accordionName){
         $scope.activeAccordion = accordionName;
    };
}]);
```

In the child directive, `my-named-directive`:

```
.directive('myNamedDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            activeAccordion: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            //a bunch of irrelevant stuff
            $scope.$watch('activeAccordion', function (newValue){
                if(newValue === "accordionOne"){
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am aware of a couple issues here.  First, it seems like the $watch is expensive and unnecessary.  More importantly, however, I take an issue with the child wanting/caring about a property on a parent object, rather than the parent dictating what the child does.

Can someone help me understand what a better approach to this in angular is?

Comment: Why are you using a custom directive. You could use:
0. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/
1. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I am using Angular UI -- it looks like there is some functionality relating to "isOpen" built in, but I am not sure how to use it.